# How to trim special chars with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

What is best way to remove all non alphanumerical chars from beginning and end of the string?

```
~~STRING~~ => STRING
"STRING" => STRING
**STRING** => STRING
**STR**ING** => STR**ING
```

Comment: `trim()` has a second parameter that allows you to specify which characters to remove

Comment: Yes I'm sorry -- I haven't read carefully.

Comment: fake duplicate top btw.

Comment: This is not a duplicate - note the tricky *****STR**ING*****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$repl = preg_replace('#^\W+|\W+$#', '', $str)
```

Comment: That removes them from the middle, too.

Comment: `\w` includes `\d`, so you don't have to list them both in the class.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes I agree using `\W` is much cleaner than negation.

Answer (score 2):

`trim($string, $charlist)` should do the trick.

Comment: That requires listing all non-alphanumeric characters in `$charlist`.

Comment: Need to prepare a long list of non-alphanumeric list.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\W*(.*\w)\W*$/', '$1', $str);
```