# How to trim special chars from string?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all non-alphanumeric signs from left and right of the string, leaving the ones in middle of string.

I've asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422668/how-to-trim-special-chars-with-php), and good solution is:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\W*(.*\w)\W*$/', '$1', $str);
```

But it does remove also some signs like ąĄćĆęĘ etc and it should not as its still alphabetical sign.

Above example would do:

```
~~AAA~~  => AAA (OK)
~~AA*AA~~ => AA*AA (OK)
~~ŚAAÓ~~  => AA (BAD)
```

Comment: when you say non alpha numeric you mean nothing other than A-Za-z0-9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you use `u` flag for unicode while using your regex.

Following works with your input:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\W*(.*\w)\W*$/u', '$1', '~~ŚAAÓ~~' );

// str = ŚAAÓ
```

**But this won't work: (Don't Use it)**

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\W*(.*\w)\W*$/', '$1', '~~ŚAAÓ~~' );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in a list of valid characters and tell the function to replace any character that is not in that list:

`$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9*]+/', '', $str);`

The square brackets say select everything in this range. The carat (`^`) is the regex for not. We then list our valid characters (lower case a to z, uppercase a to z, numbers from 0 to 9, and an asterisks). The plus symbol on the end of the square bracket says select 0 or more characters.

Edit:

If this is the list of all characters you want to keep, then:

`$str = preg_replace('/[^ĄąĆćŻżŹźŃńŁłÓó*]+/', '', $str);`